# Plotly graph embedded in rmarkdown works as email attachment but does not display if opened from the file

Tags: r, graph, r-markdown, plotly

I have a HTML file created in RMarkdown, with an embedded Plotly graph.  If I include the file as an email attachment, everything works fine--the plotly graph is displayed, the widgets work, etc.

However, if I just navigate to the file and open it (can only use IE 11 at my location) there is an empty space where the plotly graph should be but the rest of the text, headings, etc. in the file are there.  Just no plotly graph.

I included a MWE below (plotly package required) and confirmed the behavior--graph displays in email attachment, does not display when I navigate to the file and open.

I don't have much experience with HTML or browser debugging and don't know where to start.

Any help greatly appreciated!

````html
---
title: "Test"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
---


<br>

### <span style="color:dodgerblue">Sample text</span>

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=F}

require(plotly)

options(stringsAsFactors = F)

cin<-data.frame(s11.y=runif(100, 1, 5),
                s15.y=runif(100, 1, 5),
                name.y=sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace=T),
                WgName.y=sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace=T),
                minNum.y=sample(8:30, 100, replace=T),
                size=runif(100,.2,1))


wid<-650

X<-"s11.y"
Y<-"s15.y"
cs <- plot_ly(cin, x = s11.y, y = s15.y,
             mode = "markers",
             color=name.y,
             hoverinfo="text", text=paste0("<b>", name.y, "</b>", "<br>", WgName.y),
             marker=list(size=minNum.y, line=list(color="#FFFFFF"), outliercolor="rgba(50,50,50,2"))
cs<-layout(cs,
           shapes=list(list(type="line",
                            line=list(opacity=.3, layer="below"),
                            x0=mean(cin[,X], na.rm=T), x1=mean(cin[,X], na.rm=T), xref="x",
                            y0=1, y1=5, yref="y"),
                       list(type="line",
                            line=list(opacity=.3, layer="below"),
                            x0=1, x1=5, xref="x",
                            y0=mean(cin[,Y], na.rm=T), y1=mean(cin[,Y], na.rm=T), yref="y")),
           xaxis=list(range=c(1,5), title="Xaxis", autotick=F, dtick=1), 
           yaxis=list(range=c(1,5), title="Yaxis", autotick=F, dtick=1),
           title="text",
           annotations=list(list(x=mean(cin[,X], na.rm=T)+.3, y=1.5, text="Average", showarrow=F),
                            list(x=1.5, y=mean(cin[,Y], na.rm=T)+.1, text="Average", showarrow=F)))




```

```{r echo = F, fig.width = 10, fig.height = 8, warning=F, message=F}
 cs
```
````

Comment: JavaScript turned on in IE? Security options?